# How to code a sin progression with c?

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

I'm pretty new in coding and trying to write a sin progression for the uni

As a formula it looks like this:

[image: the picture of the progression]

So I tried to code it... And somehow, it calculates the radian but not the sinus... What is wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double n, a;

int fakultaet(double a = 2 * n + 1)
{
  if (a == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return (a * fakultaet(a - 1));
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double sin, y, f; // sin = Sinus, y= angle, n=index
    printf("please insert the angle \n");
    scanf("%lf", &y);

    double x = y * 3.14159265359 * 1 / 180; // x = radian measure

    while (n < 5)
    {
        sin = pow(-1, n) * pow(x, 2 * n + 1) / fakultaet(a);
    }

    printf("The sinus is %lf\n", sin);

    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because n never gets to 5?

Comment: So how shall I change it? I mean, we wherent told when the progression shall end, so I decided to finish it somehow... Shall I set n=5?

Comment: And C is our uni subjaect, had c++ in colledge and now java and c in the uni xD

Comment: In your loop you need to increment `n`. Perhaps you wanted a for loop.

Comment: Why is `n` a double? Why is it declared outside of `main()`?

Comment: `int fakultaet(double a = 2 * n + 1)` will not do what you think. Hint: `2 * n + 1` does not get executed since you pass a value. Even if you did not pass a value it would not work.

Comment: Lot of Non-C stuff in there. If you need to hand in C code, you may have problems with the marking.

Comment: Hmmm, I thougt as it was in the function and main function I shall declare n outside ...

And I did it with for loop, it worked but the sinus isn't right now...

Comment: @jesper-juhl The code is written in C++. And now an answer too.

Comment: `_tmain` is not a compliant entry into a C program on hosted environments. And this is C++, not C! (just bad coding style - why not use iostream methods?)

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing the sin, or the n. Also hardcoding the entry value for the factorial is not good. 
It should look more like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int fakultaet(double a)
{
  if (a == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return (a * fakultaet(a - 1));
}

int main()
{

    double sin = 0, y, f; // sin = Sinus, y= angle, n=index
    printf("please insert the angle \n");
    scanf("%lf", &y);

    double x = y * 3.14159265359 * 1 / 180; // x = radian measure

    for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
    {
        sin += pow(-1, n) * pow(x, 2 * n + 1) / fakultaet(2 * n + 1);
    }

    printf("The sinus is %lf\n", sin);

    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I made several edits. I turned the factorial function:

```
int fakultaet(double a = 2 * n + 1)
```

into an non hardcoded version:

```
int fakultaet(double a)
```

Added the sin initialization:

```
double sin = 0
```

Changed your while loop:

```
while (n < 5)
```

Into a for which includes the increment that was missing as well:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
```

Also turned the sin calculation:

```
sin = pow(-1, n) * pow(x, 2 * n + 1) / fakultaet(a);
```

Into one that sums:

```
sin += pow(-1, n) * pow(x, 2 * n + 1) / fakultaet(2 * n + 1);
```

Comment: @drescherjm indeed, thanks for noticing that

Comment: so why did you set sin 0?

Comment: ***why did you set sin 0*** If you don't set it `sin` will be uninitialized (possibly containing a random garbage value from memory which will make your calculation garbage..).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a neater and more efficient result by observing that
adjacent terms in the sum are related. We can express this as a recurrence:

- `T_n = - T_{n-1} x^2 /((2n+1) (2n))`
- `T_0 = x`

This is better since it avoids calls to `pow` and the need to make any explicit factorial calculations (`fakultaet`).

The code looks something like:

```
int main() {
  ...
  double T = x;
  double sin = T;
  for(int i=1 ; i<5; ++i) {
    T *= -(x*x) / ((2*i+1)*(2*i));
    sin += T;
  }
  ...
}
```